# The size of the hidden tensor in encoder-decoder example in tensor 2.0 NMT?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Can anyone suggest why the line "hidden = [tf.zeros((1, units))]" in [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)  is correct? I think it should be "hidden = tf.zeros((1, units))".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `hidden = [tf.zeros((1, units))]` is used by the `encoder`. Specifically, `hidden` is passed to `encoder.call()` as the second input argument. The definition of `encoder.call()` is:

```py
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    # ... Omitted some code...
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

  def call(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, state = self.gru(x, initial_state = hidden)
    return output, state
```

As you can see, `hidden` is passed to `self.gru.call()` as its `initial_state`. According to [the documentation of `tf.keras.layers.GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU?version=stable), initial state must be a list and the length of the list must match the number of internal states of the RNN. In this case, the RNN is a GRU and there is one internal state. Hence the length-1 list you see.

Comment: Thanks. I completely missed this point in the definition of GRU. However, I experimented with a single tensor instead of a list, it worked in that case also.